# TurtleBot3 HDMI not working

Tags: turtlebot, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My team and me have problems to get the HDMI output working on Intel Joule, required to setup Ubuntu on TurtleBot3.
We tried several monitors, micro HDMI cables and converters, but we never got any output.

It does seem that the problem is related to the Intel Joule itself, as we were not able to retrieve any output also during the early boot stage (BIOS).

Nevertheless, the board itself is working, as we can interact with the running Joule via the serial command line interface.

There are numerous posts on Intel's panels, but none of these came up with a working solution.

BIOS version is #193

https://communities.intel.com/thread/113459
https://communities.intel.com/thread/108466?start=15&tstart=0
https://discourse.ros.org/t/waffle-hdmi-no-signal/2687/7
https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/77

Best Regards,
Jürgen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279125/turtlebot3-hdmi-not-working/) by [juergen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33189/juergen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
connect your micro hdmi when u startup joule you press the  f7 button to startup from usb to install ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [bajramg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30188/bajramg/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0